# RDP to server with invalid cert only works on Windows 2012

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2, windows-server-2012, rdp

I'm trying to RDP to a client's server. When trying from Windows 2008 R2, I get the following error after being prompted for my credentials:

[image: From Windows 2008 R2]

When I try from Windows 2012, I get an error about the certificate and if I choose to ignore, it connects normally:

[image: From Windows 2012]

Why don't I get the option to ignore that error and connect anyways from Windows 2008 R2?

Comment: What are your RDP settings on the 2012 box?

Comment: On the 2K8R2 box check the server authentication options on the Advanced tab.

Comment: Are you using Network Level Authentication at W2K8 side ?

Comment: Server auth is set to "warn me", and I already tried the option to just connect. I am using NLA which is why I'm being prompted for login before the session is opened.

Answer (score 0):

I think W2012 shipped with a new version of RDP. Have you tried upgrading your Windows RDP client on your W2K8 box ?

Comment: Where could I find that update? The system is pretty current on automatic updates from what I can see.

Comment: @Rico : i don't think an update can solve the problem, i connect everyday using RDP to non updated w2k8R2 servers (i know, bad...). I got certificate warning but have no issues to connect

Comment: This is for example an article describing the changes in the new Remote Desktop Protocol (8.1) http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2830477/en-us . otherwise you can try an alternative client like 2x: http://www.2x.com/rdp-client/windows-linux-mac/downloadlinks/